# How to be notified of Debian package updates without using apt?

Tags: debian

Is there a way (RSS, mailing list, some site...?) to be notified when Debian updates a package? I mean any package, not a particular one or the ones I have installed on my machine.

Comment: Do you think on some automatic update mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `debian-devel-changes` mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-changes/) receives a copy of the upload descriptions for all packages uploaded to Debian unstable and experimental, [`debian-changes`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-changes/) to stable, [`debian-backports-changes`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-backports-changes/) to backports. [`debian-security-announce`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/) receives all security announcements (when they’re ready for publication).

You can subscribe to those to be notified of all package uploads (which means *a lot* of email).